# Less Selector: second last element if last element has specific id

Tags: less

I have a setup that runs and generates X number of column headers, and then possibly a last header with an id of **"lastColumn"**. I do not know the number of columns being generated and cannot change that generative code.

I need to add a style to the last **class="cell"** only if **id="lastColumn"** exists. Is this possible using only css/less selectors? Last resort is to handle it via javascript, but I am hoping to avoid that if at all possible.

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/1atk6kv0/2/)

I have tried combinations of the following, but have not been successful.

```css
&:nth-last-child(2)
&:nth-child(2) ~ #lastColumn
#lastColumn ~ &:nth-child(2)
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current way? That is to use `.cell#lastColumn` selector? That would work only when the `id` is present.

Comment: Sorry, might have explained that strangely.I need to apply the style not to id="lastColumn", but id="item-anotherUniqueName" in the fiddle example. Problem is, I don't know what its id is going to be. Only that I need to apply the style to it, if the next element (lastColumn) exists.

Comment: No, as far as I know this is not possible with CSS because you are trying to select a previous sibling. It is not possible with Less also because Less ultimately compiles into CSS.